# Cross browser fetch response validation

Tags: javascript, httpresponse, fetch-api

How can I check that the response from a JavaScript fetch is valid (status 200), in a way that works cross browser?

The only solution I've found would be to read the response as an ArrayBuffer and manually checking the content byte by byte to see if it is a valid file or not. Not very practical.

In my case the fetch is in a service worker, so I don't know what kind of resource is being fetched (html document, image, binary file, etc), I just want to take different actions depending on it being successful or not.

```
fetch('http://example.com/some_resource')
.then(function(response)
{
   if (response.ok)
   {
       // Works for most browsers, but not Chrome and Firefox on Android 
   }
   response.arrayBuffer().thenCheckEveryByteOfTheFile;  // Do I really have to do this?
});
```

UPDATE:
The MDN documentation is wrong. Response.ok is defined for Chrome and Firefox on Android.

https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/9309

Comment: How do you define 'valid'. You're naming quite a few different formats including 'binary file'. Why are you checking byte-by-byte? Surely there's a quicker way to ensure validity for at least some of these formats?

Comment: @Evert: The simplest way would be if I could get access to the first line of the HTTP response, which typically is "HTTP/1.1 200 OK". Then I could parse that and see if it was successful or not. But since not all browsers have access to it, I would have to read the response payload, then if the URL ends with ".jpg" check that the first bytes are FF D8 FF. I think you get the point. Extremely impractical for something that should be very simple.

Comment: @Evert: I have HTML files, CSS files, Font files, WEBP files, JPG files, plus many different kinds of binary responses from CGI scrips.

Comment: Ok, your definition of 'valid' is a bit different. You're looking for success responses, which makes sense. Why does `response.ok` not work for you on chrome and firefox?

Comment: I suspect that this has to do with CORS

Comment: Thanks @Evert. Response.ok and response.status are not defined on mobile (Chrome and Firefox). There is no way to know what the actual content is, other than inspecting it byte by byte. A request for an image could result in a HTML page with a server error message.

Comment: response.ok certainly is defined in Chrome and Firefox, including mobile. It's a pretty integral part of the fetch API. If you don't see a `.ok` I feel it's more likely that there is some other issue.

And it's still not clear what you mean byte-by-byte. What will each byte tell you?

Comment: @Evert: I hoped that would be true, but it isn't. Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response  Check here too:  https://caniuse.com/?search=response.ok

Comment: @Evert: Suppose you have a file without a file extension, how would you find out what kind of file it is? You'd have to check it byte by byte. If it starts with FF D8 FF it is likely a JPG file. When you make a HTTP request to for example http://test.com/Image.jpg, the response could either be that image or it could be a server message that the image is missing. Without access to response.ok, how can I tell what is sent back?

Comment: Ok you are talking about the magic bytes. Reading those does not mean it's valid though. If you are just trying to find out what type a response is, your best bet it probably actually using the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Anyway, I have a feeling that `caniuse.com` is wrong. Have you tested the android browsers?

Comment: I'm just so skeptical because we use `fetch()` extensively and never ran into an issue like this on android. Our library throws an exception if `response.ok` is falsy.

Comment: I've filed an issue about this on Github. Let's see how they respond. I agree it makes no sense for these browsers to not support response.ok, so the docs might be wrong. https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/2785

Comment: @Evert: you are correct, and I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `fetch()` objects' properties are not (officially) fully compatible, especially on the mobile side with Chrome/Firefox/Opera on Android, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status#browser_compatibility), as of today.

It is not an option for you as you are using a *Service Worker*, on which regular Ajax support has been dropped. XHR won't be defined there, and you can only make use of the `fetch()` API.

Otherwise, you could have gone with an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status), which retains full official cross-browser compatibility.

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/some_resource');
xhr.send();

//When response is received
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status == 200) { // xhr.status is compatible with Android
        console.log(xhr.response); 
        //OK!
  } else { 
        console.log(xhr.response); 
        //OOPS, not OK!
  }
};
```

Regardless of this, if you try writing this script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    fetch('https://whateverfreeapiyoucanthink.of')
    .then(function(response)
    {
       alert(response.status);
    });
    }
```

And then open the page from an Android device, it works for me on both
*Chrome 88* and *Firefox 86* using *Android 8.0.0*, although it's not officially supported. If nothing, this is worth taking note of, as it would prove the MDN wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but response.status and response.statusText is not defined for Chrome and Firefox on Android. If there was a way to access the status line of the HTTP response, this would be simple. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: Thanks @BiOS, your suggestion would work great on the client side. But my code is in a service worker, and as I understand it XHR is not guaranteed to be defined there, since it is a legacy API. It bugs me that the Response object gives no access to the overall HTTP response, only a parsed version where some browsers throw away the status part. This makes no sense to me. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You are indeed right again on the XHR, and in fact I was not aware of its dropped support on service workers. I have again updated the answer to reflect the good information your provided and not mislead anybody. However I was running some tests out of curiosity and I have noticed that `alert(response.status)` (The best I could try without a proper console) actually works from both Firefox and Chrome on Android 8. That implies that response.status is actually read. However, I guess that you tried that already, regardless of MDN warnings?

Comment: Thanks for testing. No, I didn't actually try it. MDN is usually always correct, and they are the devs behind Firefox, so they should know. And the Google's dev pages refer to MDN. I've filed a comment on this at Github. Let's see how they respond. https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/2785

Comment: You are correct, and I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: That was indeed an interesting one, and I am curious to see when they will get it updated on their side! For the time being we better send feedbacks to caniuse and the MDN. And hopefully your question will be found by anybody experiecing the same!

Comment: Yea they are not very quick to update their documentation. Still reads the same...

Comment: Response.ok now updated in documentation, but Response.status still the same, LOL.

Comment: Indeed, seen it! As you may see from [here](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/9335), they have already raised the point of `response.status`, but they are waiting for another issue to be created before addressing `response.status` too... Perhaps it'd better to create an issue about the whole Response object! BTW caniuse is now mirroring the correct [info](https://caniuse.com/?search=response.ok) too